# SQL Server query through view and query through base tables get different execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, sql-execution-plan

I have a view which is basically joining some tables and there are no indexes on the view. When I query against the view(joined with another table), the performance is bad, which takes about 10 minutes. When I extract the base tables from the view and joined with "another table", it takes about 20 seconds. The logic to use the view or use the base tables is exactly the same. I checked the and they do get different execution plans. Any ideas why could this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server may be using an cached execution plan (Based upon the first time you selected something from the view. That table may have grown in size and is no longer using the most efficient plan, hence the slow performance).

You could refresh the view using:

`sp_refreshview [ @viewname = ] 'viewname'`

Or rebuild the view entirely and run it again to generate a fresh execution plan, however you may run into the same performance trouble later on.  This article describes what could be happening in further detail:

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/views-general/

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx

Comment: Who down vote this answer? I remember it's 2 up vote last night, now it's just one.

Comment: @Yousui glad to hear you got it sorted :-)